# I have a page with a non-scrollabe left side-bar and a scrollable right container. I want to add a "go to top" button in the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have written the code so that it will show up after the page is scrolled 20px. But with this code the button does not show up. The problem here is that when the side-bar and container both are scrolled, the button works fine. I want it to work when only the right container is scrolled

```js
//go to top button
var topBtn = document.getElementById('top');
var contain = document.getElementsByClassName('container').scrollTop;

window.onscroll = function(){
    scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction(){
    if (document.contain > 20){
        topBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        topBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function goToTop(){
    document.contain = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

topBtn.addEventListener('click', goToTop);
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav role="navigation" id="nav">
        <img class="profile-img" src="images/profile-photo-new.jpg" alt="" />
        <a href="#about" class="nav-links">About</a>
        <a href="#experience" class="nav-links">Experience</a>
        <a href="#education" class="nav-links">Education</a>
        <a href="#skills" class="nav-links">Skills</a>
        <a href="#interests" class="nav-links">Interests</a>
        <a href="#certificates" class="nav-links">Certificates</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="about" class="mtb about-fixed-nav">
          <h1 class="heading about-head">
            <span>Pratit</span>
            Bangdiwala
          </h1>
        <a href="#" id="top">Top</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### No need Javascript

Use this

```
 <a href="#nav" id="top">Top</a>
```

Use the Id of top element of your page as "href" value
Like "nav"